# How do I summon mobs with block heads on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't figure it out. I can only summon mobs with other mob heads. I've been wanting to summon a cow with a water source block head and name it " Underwater Mission Fail"— Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is possible with cows (or any other non-armor-supporting mob). I do know it is possible with Skeletons and Zombies, however. The command is in the below format:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:46}]}
```

The above command will spawn a Zombie with a TNT block for a head. I think water can be done, if you really want. Simply replace that 46 with something else.

Command Breakdown:

```
/summon <mobType> <x> <y> <z> {Equipment:[{id:<weaponID>},{id:<bootArmorID>},{id:<pantsArmorID>},{id:<shirtArmorID>},{id:<headArmorID}] <otherNBTTags>}
```

Note that blocks can only be head armor and not any other armor. You can however place other things into these slots for a chance of drop on death.

---

For a zombie wearing water and named "Underwater Mission Fail" (in bold red), run this command:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:10}] Name:&4&lUnderwater_Mission_Fail}
```

---

In the 1.8 and above snapshots, you need to use the block name instead of the block ID. For example, spawning a Zombie wearing only TNT for a head will have this command instead of the above:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:tnt}]}
```

Comment: The last command does not work! Also you are not able to replace the head with water on a Zombie neiter a Skeleton. The water is in the body of the mob and not on the head...

Comment: Interesting. Thanks Garret. The last command is missing a bracket (***Fixed***). Also, Minecraft kinda sucks at rendering things sometimes. The "Head in Water" idea was kind of a "whaaaaaaaaaaat?" moment for me. Neither Hypixel or SethBling did it yet.

Comment: Note that with the 1.8 snapshots IDs are no longer usable. Use the block name instead (i.e. "stone" for stone, "log:3" for Jungle Log, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {Equipment:[{Damage:8261,id:373},{id:313},{id:313},{id:313},{Damage:3,id:397,tag:{SkullOwner:CrunkleSticks}}]}