# What's the /summon syntax to summon equipped mobs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What I need to type when I want to summon "equipped" mobs? I want to summon headless zombies(wearing air on their head). So, can you tell me what to type in the chat(after "summon zombie") for each part of the body's equipment, please? Edit:Tell me also on other parts of the body.

Comment: Search before asking, please. Completely answered here: [How do I summon mobs with block heads on Minecraft?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181326/how-do-i-summon-mobs-with-block-heads-on-minecraft)

Comment: Also, I am not sure wearing invisible block will make mob's head invisible...

Comment: How do I unduplicate the question? I asked for each part of the body,not just the head. @Orc JMR

Comment: Please read the answer to suggested question, on the seventh line it describes the syntax for all equipment slots. If, after that, you still want to reopen your question, contact a moderator, they are able to do that, but they dislike people who don't follow links :-)

Comment: I saw now that it can be scrolled to to the right. @Orc JMR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:air}]}
```

That command is used to summon a Zombie wearing air on its head. It still has a head though, as air is invisible and you can still see the zombie's head through it.